# Rendering view from non-file source in Nancy

Tags: nancy

I have a fairly typical Nancy configuration, with views being served from locations on the file system.

Under a specific route I wish to serve views which are not stored on the file system, but will be provided in Markdown format from an external service.

I initially approached the idea by considering creating a custom concrete class for `IViewLocationProvider` which would deal with locating the views from the external service.  By my understanding of Nancy (and I could be wrong here), you can only have one `IViewLocationProvider`, so adding this custom class would mean that I could not get the rest of the pages (for all my other routes) from the file system.

My approach is now to manually call the `Nancy.ViewEngines.Markdown.Render` method, passing it my Markdown (encapsulated in a `Func<TextReader>`) and a fake `ViewLocationResult`.  As so:

```
public class MyModule
{
    public MyModule(ExternalServiceAdapter externalService, MarkDownViewEngine viewEngine, IRenderContext renderContext) : base("/MyPath")
    {
        Get["/{Name}/{Version}/View"] = parameters => SpecialView(viewEngine, renderContext, externalService, (string)parameters.Name, (string)parameters.Version);
    }


    protected static Response SpecialView(MarkDownViewEngine viewEngine, IRenderContext renderContext, ExternalServiceAdapter externalService, string name, string version)
    {
        var contents = externalService.GetData(name, version);            
        var location = new ViewLocationResult(string.Empty, string.Empty, "md", contents);
        return viewEngine.RenderView(location, null, renderContext); //FIXME fails when performing Master page substitution in Super Simple View Engine
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the Markdown includes an SSVE `@Master['master']` tag which causes the above to fall down at the indicated line with a null reference exception deep within SSVE.  (I have a file on the file system which is named *master* and is in Nancy's default path convention for views - but I don't think it's the presence of the file which is causing the issue)

Is there a better approach to rendering a Nancy view from markdown which is not located on the file system?  (yet maintain a file system provider for other routes)